# android - ListView.setAdapter error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException" by setting my adapter in ListFragment activity.

Here is my code:

```
private List<Music> musicList;
public View inflate;
ListView searchList;
public class SearchFragment extends ListFragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);
        musicList = new ArrayList<Music>();
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(musicList, context);
        searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have a NullPointerException in the following code:

The error is at `searchList.setAdapter(adapter);` so i also try to change to adapter value from `new ArrayList<Music>()` to `new <Music>ArrayList()` but no luck.

My Music class looks like this:

```
public class Music {
    private String title, thumbnail, duration, uri, waveform;
    private int likes, playbackCount;

    public Music() {
    }

    public Music(String name, String thumbnailUrl, int likes, String rating, int playbackCount) {
        this.title = name;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.duration = rating;
        this.playbackCount = playbackCount;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }
    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public int getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }
    public void setLikes(int likes) { this.likes = likes; }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public int getPlayBackCount() {
        return playbackCount;
    }
    public void setPlayBackCount(int playbackCount) {
        this.playbackCount = playbackCount;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }
    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getWaveform() {
        return waveform;
    }
    public void setWaveform(String waveform) {
        this.waveform = waveform;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this 
    
    You get the NullPointerException Because you are not write below statement in you
    
    code before the set adepter. You must initialize your list view
    
      ListView searchList=(ListView)inflate.findViewById(R.id.searchList);

Answer (score 1):

You already extends `ListFragment` so

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

take a look [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm)

Answer (score 1):

First, You have taken `ListView searchList` and the same object you haven't initialized so it's giving you NullPointerException while calling `searchList.setAdapter(adapter);`.

Second, you have taken `ListFragment` so you can directly get listview using `getListView()` method. Even you can directly call `setListAdapter(adapter)` method.